# Converting an ONNX model to PyTorch witch onnx2torch library gives huge differences

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, onnx

I have found an ONNX model (already trained) for pupil identification in eye images, which works very well. But I would like to use it as a PyTorch model, so I am trying to convert it from ONNX to PyTorch.
As displayed in the following code, I am using the convertModel function from the onnx2pytorch library available at https://github.com/Talmaj/onnx2pytorch

```py
from onnx2pytorch import ConvertModel
onnx_model = onnx.load("onnx_model.onnx")
pytorch_model = ConvertModel(onnx_model)
```

Then I tried to run the two models on the same input image.

```py
# load input image and some preprocessing
img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("images/eye_frame_00494.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 240), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2)
img = clahe.apply(img)

img2 = img.reshape(1, 240, 320, 1)
img2 = img2 / 255
test_img_input = np.zeros((1, 240, 320, 3), dtype=np.float32)
test_img_input[:, :, :, :] = img2

# convert to tensor for pytorch model
input_img = torch.tensor(test_img_input)

# predictions
result = session.run([output_name], {input_name: test_img_input})
# there is some lines above to define *output_name *and *input_name *properly
output = pytorch_model(input_img)
```

But then, when I plot the result of the channel that interests me, it gives 2 differents prediction (as shown in following image).

[Differences in predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZbww.png)

I tried on some other images and there is always a difference, sometimes very small, sometimes very problematic. Can someone help me to explain where this difference might come from, and how to correct it (or at least lower it).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just adding the line

```
pytorch_model.eval()
```

allowed me to get the exact same prediction.